# Get value of behaviour property from CallOperationAction in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

Hi if we drag an drop an operation into an activity diagram it would create as a **CallOperationAction** type of action. In CallOperationAction we have a property called **behaviour** under the **call** tab .

The values which we give here will be stored in the table  `t_object.ClassifierGUID`.But unfortunately there isn't any property called  `ClassifierGUID` in the element class. Is there any other way to get the value other than querying ?

I even tried the **classifierID** property but no luck :(

Answer (score 2):

No that property is not exposed by the API, but you can still get it.

In my framework I use the following code in the class [CallOperationAction](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EAWrappers/CallOperationAction.cs)

```
/// <summary>
/// The operation to be invoked by the action execution.
/// </summary>
public UML.Classes.Kernel.Operation operation { 
    get{
        // first get the operations guid which is stored in the Classifier_guid column
        XmlDocument operationGUIDxml = this.model.SQLQuery(@"select o.Classifier_guid from t_object o
                            where o.Object_ID = " + this.id.ToString());
        XmlNode operationGUIDNode = operationGUIDxml.SelectSingleNode(this.model.formatXPath("//Classifier_guid"));
        return this.model.getOperationByGUID(operationGUIDNode.InnerText);
    }
}
```